# How to make invisible ASP.NET controls within a certain div tag?

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdown "ddl_group" list followed by two  tags containing controls related to item chosen in the first. One item in ddl_group is *teacher* and another item is *student.* By default, I have set all controls within the two div tags to invisible. They only show up when a group related to them is chosen in ddl_group. 
Imagine I choose student in ddl_group. Next, controls within div.stdInfo start to appear one after the other in response to user who makes choices on controls within div.stdInfo. Now the user might want to choose another group i.e. teacher from ddl_group. Therefore, I'll need to make invisible again all controls within div.stdInfo and make visible controls within div.teacherInfo. 

Is it possible to make invisible or visible all asp.net controls within a certain tag (e.g. div tag) in one place rather than setting them individually?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your div in

[ASP.NET Panel Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel(v=vs.110).aspx)

then you can make it

> pnlName.Visible=true; or  pnlName.Visible=false;

when ever you want or 
you can use Div with

> runat="server"

attribute so that it is accessible in code page
their you can do  it like

> divname.Visible=true; divname.Visible=false;

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ASP.NET Place holder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder(v=vs.110).aspx) or [ASP.NET Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel(v=vs.110).aspx) controls for these purposes.

1. Wrap your content with Place holder or Panel.
2. On SelectedIndexChanged event of your drop down, you can change visibility of this PlaceHolder or Panel.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `runat` tag and an ID tag to your `divs`, that will make them accessible via server side code. I prefer this way because I don't have to mess-up my css at all.

e.g.

**markup:**

```
<div class='teacherinfo' ID='teacherDiv' runat='server'>
.
.
.
.
.
</div>
```

**code behind:**

```
teacherDiv.Visible = false;
```

**One word of warning**, making a server-side control invisible means that it will not be present on the resulting html document. So if you try to find it with javascript `document.getElementById("<%= teacherDiv.ClientId %>")`, you'll get an error.